# How do I get the inner text of a label before an input element?

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

My app is using htmlagility pack. As of right now I can get all the input elements on a form. The problem is that I am getting ALL the input elements by ID. I am trying to narrow it down to only give me input elements of a form by ID that contain exact inner text labels before each input element.

Example:

```
<label for="email">Email Address:</label>
<input type="text" class="textbox" name="email" id="email" maxlength="50" value="" dir="ltr" tabindex="1"
```

I am trying to get the input that has a proceeding label with the inner text of "Email Address"

How would I word this?

Here is my app that grabs ALL input elements by ID.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim doc As HtmlDocument
    Dim web As New HtmlWeb
    doc = web.Load("http://shaggybevo.com/board/register.php")
    Dim docNode As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode
    Dim nodes As HtmlNodeCollection = docNode.SelectNodes("//input")
    'SelectNodes takes a XPath expression
    For Each node As HtmlNode In nodes
        'Get all input elements by id
        Dim id As String = node.GetAttributeValue("value", "id")

        'print all input elements by id to form2 richtextbox
        Form2.RichTextBox1.Text = Form2.RichTextBox1.Text & Environment.NewLine & id.ToString & name.ToString()
        Form2.Show()

    Next

End Sub
```

Thanks guys....I have to say I've been studying VB.NET for a while and to date this forum has been awesome...glad I found it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic concept here is to get the labels whose `for` attribute matches the id of the associated `input`.

So, we cycle through the labels first and record the label's text in a dictionary that is keyed by the `for` value, then we cycle through the `inputs` and if the id of the input is in the dictionary, we retrieve the value from the dictionary (which is the label text) and show it.

Note that I have also modified how the data is collected to be more efficient (almost any time you concatenate strings, you should use stringbuilder).

Here's the rewritten code:

```
    Dim web As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb()
    Dim doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = web.Load("http://shaggybevo.com/board/register.php")
    Dim nodes As HtmlNodeCollection

    ' Keeps track of the labels by the associated control id
    Dim labelText As New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)

    ' First, get the labels
    nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//label")

    If nodes IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each node In nodes
            If node.Attributes.Contains("for") Then
                Dim sFor As String

                ' Extract the for value
                sFor = node.Attributes("for").Value

                ' If it does not exist in our dictionary, add it
                If Not labelText.ContainsKey(sFor) Then
                    labelText.Add(sFor, node.InnerText)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

    nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input")

    Dim sbText As New System.Text.StringBuilder(500)

    If nodes IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each node In nodes
            ' See if this input is associated with a label
            If labelText.ContainsKey(node.Id) Then
                ' If it is, add it to our collected information
                sbText.Append("Label = ").Append(labelText(node.Id))
                sbText.Append(", Id = ").Append(node.Id)

                sbText.AppendLine()
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Form2.RichTextBox1.Text = sbText.ToString
    Form2.Show()
```

Comment: WOW!!! My year is made....thanks again competent_tech. As soon as I get enough questions built up to give rep....I will be back to hook you up with the proper rep you deserve for helping me out so much.

Comment: That's great news! I also posted an answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380486/html-agility-pack-trying-to-get-inputs-getelementbyid-or-class-and-put-into